# Fill a column in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Is it possible, on a single select, to fill a extra column on my select if the result satisfies a condition?

For example:

I have a table with 4 columns.

On a select, I want to, if hold_time is greater than X fill another column with another value:

```
      dac          | name  | call_duration | hold_time 
-------------------+-------+---------------+-----------
 Desenvolvimento   | 40018 |             1 |        13
 Desenvolvimento   | 40018 |            25 |         5
 Desenvolvimento   | 40018 |             2 |         6
```

If hold_time > 10 fill another column (that don't exist) with 'OK'.

Comment: You can use a `CASE` expression for this, like: `CASE WHEN hold_time > 10 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOT OK END AS otherCol`

Comment: Thanks man, thats what I need!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN hold_time > 10 THEN 'OK' END AS new_column
FROM   mytable
```